# Cardinality vs width in the ResNext architecture

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, resnet

I was recently reading the paper [Aggregated Residual Transformations for Deep Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05431).

One thing the author mentions in **Section (5.1)** is that increasing the cardinality (or, the number of branches), decreases validation error more than increasing the bottleneck width or increasing the depth. I understand the depth part, but I'm a bit confused about the width. Isn't the cardinality of a residual block the same as the bottleneck width? If not, what is the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the width is the width of the bottleneck layer and the cardinality is the number of branches in a residual block.